# Using private types with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, private, auto

With `auto` I can create variables of a private type. For example, if for any reason, I create a public function returning an object of a private type, I could receive variables of that type with `auto`:

```
class A
{
private:
  struct B {};

public:
  B& public_function_because_of_a_mistake();
};

A a;
auto& b = a.public_function_because_of_mistake();

// Perhaps, struct A::B is not properly design to support copying of elements.
// In the natural use of the class B (inside A), perhaps,
// there is no copy of objects of type B, so, the programmer didn't take
// the proper precautions.
decltype(b) b2 = b; // Unintended copy

// Perhaps the user wanted to call other function with same name, thinking 'b' was 
// of another class.
b.something_unintended();
```

I know such a situation (so many unintented mistakes) is highly unlikely, but, anyway, isn't it a "security" or "design" hole? Because the main focus of C++ is to prevent unintented actions by means of a strict type system and access control rules, and `auto` can skip them easily.

Comment: This also compiles: `decltype(a.public_function_because_of_a_mistake()) b = a.public_function_because_of_a_mistake();`

Comment: I'm not aware of any real-world bug that was caused by such an inadvertent use of a private type. Are you?